# 3 simular methods with very different results in wpf when moving a simple rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an odd problem with tasks in wpf applications. I created a simple program and placed a rectangle on it named "RectObj" with a button that calls one of the 3 methods. I'm trying to slide it across the screen smoothly using C# code. I dont want to use animations, I genuinely want to know why the following code does what it does in each case and how to fix it without animations?

```
// has a delay in the initial few moments without moving, then jumps to it's position and thereafter runs perfectly smooth even after another button press
    public void test()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((() =>
                {
                    var margin = RectObj.Margin;
                    margin.Left = testValue++;
                    RectObj.Margin = margin;
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        });
    }
    // runs, but jagged movements/refreshing
    public void test2()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((() =>
                {
                    var margin = RectObj.Margin;
                    margin.Left = testValue++;
                    RectObj.Margin = margin;
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }));
            }
        });
    }
    // does not update display until task is completed
    public void test3()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((() =>
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                {
                    var margin = RectObj.Margin;
                    margin.Left = testValue++;
                    RectObj.Margin = margin;
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            }));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case one, I don't really know why you have a delay the first time. I guess it's doing some kind of initialization (otherwise you'd have the delay every time you press the button), but I'm not sure what precisely.

For case two and three, you must understand two things:

- Whatever is inside your `Dispatcher.Invoke` gets executed by the UI thread
- The UI isn't refreshed while a dispatcher callback is running. Long story short, the UI thread executes an infinite loop that alternates between refreshing the UI (that is, drawing what should be on screen, depending on the value of the controls), and executing whatever callback you queued with the dispatcher

From there, it's easy to understand what happens:

- In case two, your `Thread.Sleep` is executed by the UI thread. While it's sleeping, it can't refresh the UI.
- In case three, you never exit the dispatcher, leaving no chance for the UI thread to redraw the screen

As to know how to fix it... Of course, the best way is to use animation. If you really don't want to, at least use a `TranslateTransform` to move your control instead of changing the margin. Using a `TranslateTransform` (assigned to the `RenderTransform` property of your control) only changes the visual appearance of the control (not the actual position), and therefore is fast. Changing the margin forces WPF to recompute part of the layout, which is CPU hungry.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. makes sense for case 2 and 3 now. I now understand how the dispatcher works. And translateTransform seems to solve the problem of the initial lag. Thanks for the help